# Regex: not matching line if it has something unwanted

Tags: regex, negative-lookbehind

I still don't seem to be able to get negative lookbehind. I have a situation where I want to be able to match all lines that have a certain string in them, iff they *don't* have a certain other string *anywhere* before it. I want to be able to find all lines that occur w/"_view" that do not have "ora" behind them. So "*blahblah*ora*blahblah*_view" should not match, but "*blahblah*_view" should. I've tried mating `(?<!ora)` with `_view` but it always hits on something w/that has anything that isn't "ora" before "_view". `[^(ora)]` also doesn't seem to get me what I want.

I also tried learning from [Perl: Matching string not containing PATTERN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23403494/perl-matching-string-not-containing-pattern) but that didn't get me anywhere. (It doesn't seem to mix positive and negative matches the way I want)

I'm also using https://regex101.com understanding that it is a robust and general tool for diagnosing regexes.

I'm not using Perl or Java but an IDE (PhpStorm), so what ever applies to `grep` should be good enough.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Also, why use lookbehind? Regex101 does not support an infinite width lookbehind as the site supports PCRE/JS and Python regex flavors. This is only supported in some few regex flavors. You may use `^(?!.*oca.*_view).*_view` based on a look*ahead*.

Comment: Could you format your question and add the IDE you use?

Comment: @Jan: this one doesn't ensure that "oca" is before "view", it can be anywhere in the string.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Right you are, [**`^(?:(?!oca).)*view.*$`**](https://regex101.com/r/nI6wV3/3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least two ways are possible:

The one that uses lookarounds:

```
^(?!.*ora.*_view).*_view.*
```

*(easy to write but not efficient, because it may cause a lot of backtracking)*

The one that uses negated character classes:

```
^[^o_]*(?:o(?!ra)[^o_]*|_(?!view)[^o_]*)*_view.*
```

or the version with possessive quantifiers (if available):

```
^[^o_]*+(?:o(?!ra)[^o_]*|_(?!view)[^o_]*)*+_view.*
```

or the version that emulates possessive quantifiers (if not available):

```
^(?=([^o_]*))\1(?=((?:o(?!ra)[^o_]*|_(?!view)[^o_]*)*))\2_view.*
```

Except if your IDE uses the .net regex engine *(that allows variable length lookbehinds)* or at least the Java regex engine *(that allows limited variable length lookbehinds)*, there's no way to use a lookbehind here.

Comment: Meh... I'd rather do the backtracking rather than comb through that yarn. But that worked great, thanks. Care to explain how you got that? I would have never figured that out. I can understand the start-of-line anchor, I understand the grouping, the lookahead and the greedy `.*`, but what I don't get is why `_view` appears in the grouping and then again outside of it.

Comment: @Opux: "view" 'appears in the grouping' to prevent an eventual '_' to be the start of the substring `_view` until `_view` is reached (doing this allows to use a greedy quantifier instead of a non-greedy quantifier that is slower). `(?!...)` is a negative lookahead and means *not followed by*.