# Regex in jmeter to not match string containing substring

Tags: regex, jmeter

My Response data is -

MyString=01015400007715243552T2867X01051005012447/3/1207/7\u0026index=2

MyString=014274**X9**000010152435500000MT2867X0154992365418/3/1207/7\u0026index=3

where i want to write a regex to match first string and ignore second string,below is my requirement.

As i highlighted in second string if the value contains X9 i should not match that string.

I tried many regex ,but dint help me much.
i tried MyString=(.*[^X9].+?)u0026
Please can someone help me

Comment: Try `MyString=((?:(?!X9).)*?)u0026`

Comment: Note that `\u0026` might actually be `&`. Try also `MyString=((?:(?!X9)[^&])*)`

Comment: thankyou ..to understand please can u tell me more about the regex u suggested.

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you may use is

```
MyString=((?:(?!X9).)*?)u0026
```

Or, to avoid matching in the backslash,

```
MyString=((?:(?!X9).)*?)\\u0026
```

Or, if `\\u0026` is actually just a representation of `&` (and you have `&` in fact), use

```
MyString=((?:(?!X9)[^&])*)
```

The `(?:(?!X9).)*?` is a [*tempered greedy token*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970) that matches any char, any 0+ times, as few as possible, that does not start a `X9` sequence.

**Details**

- `MyString=` - a literal substring
- `((?:(?!X9).)*?)` - any char, 0+ repetitions, as few as possible (since `*?` is a lazy quantifier that forces the regex engine to skip the quantifyable pattern first and try all subsequent ones, and only if they fail to match this one is "expanded"), up to the first occurrence of `X9`
- `u0026` - a literal substring

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the following regular expression:

```
MyString=(?:(?!X9).)*\\u0026
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Regular Expression Not Match]

References:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl: Matching string not containing PATTERN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23403494/perl-matching-string-not-containing-pattern)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

Comment: thanks for helping always :)  please can u tell me more about the regex ..for my understanding ..thanks in advance