# ? matched expression does not print in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I rarely write Perl and don't know how to phrase the question. I am using Perl as a "filter" to go through files.

```
echo "this is a test" | perl -pe 's/(this).*(test)?/\1 \2/'
```

returns only

```
this
```

I am looking for

```
this test
```

Comment: your code doesn't output `this` for me... it outputs a blank line. Are you sure that's what you're running?

Comment: @msb sorry, I was missing the parentheses for the first match. edited.

Comment: Oh ok. Now it makes sense. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regexes (the feature within the first section of the `s///` operator) match against the provided text sequentially, greedily. This means that it will first find `this` (easy enough), then `.*` will match the entire rest of the string. `(test)?` is matched against the remaining string, which is nothing, and since it's optional, it succeeds.

One way to prevent `.*` from matching the rest of the string before the next part can try is to make it non-greedy, this is done by attaching the `?` [quantifier modifier](https://perldoc.pl/perlre#Quantifiers) (not to be confused with the `?` quantifier which means zero-or-one). But this doesn't help here, because then it will just match the empty string (as the shortest string it can match), and `(test)?` will also still match the empty string afterward since it's not immediately followed by `test`.

Depending what you are trying to do, there are a couple possible solutions. First would be to make the `(test)` group non-optional by removing the `?`, which will cause the match to try smaller and smaller matches for `.*` until the following text successfully matches `(test)` (a regex feature known as [backtracking](https://perldoc.pl/perlre#Backtracking)). Another option is anchoring the match to the end of the string with `$` after a non-greedy `.*?` so that it will always look for `(test)` at the end of the string before falling back to matching the empty string (via sort of reverse backtracking).

```
/(this).*(test)/
/(this).*?(test)?$/
```

As a side note, your replacement variables should be `$1` and `$2`, not `\1` and `\2`; backslash variables are for use within the regex itself, and using them in the replacement is only supported as it's a feature of sed.

Comment: Thank you. How would you suggest I rewrite the regex? I'm can't seem to remove the parts in between 'this' and 'test'.

Comment: @user121392 It really depends on what your specific inputs are and what you're trying to do. The options I presented in the answer are as much as I could suggest generically.

Comment: the generic way to match any (non-newline) character up to but not including an optional "test" would be `(?:(?!test).)*` (so in full, `/(this)(?:(?!test).)*(test)?/`)

Comment: It is a string with an optional match in the middle ('test'), so anchoring to the end would not work. I am looking to extract specific parts of a string which have optional matches in the middle.

Comment: @ysth I think your final regex is missing an opening parentheses. I can't get it to work.

Comment: it was missing one briefly, I added it; try again?

Comment: @ysth Thank you. It worked. While I am reading up on non-capturing groups, why did you add (?!test) instead of (!test) and the . behind (?!test) ?

Comment: @user121392 `(?!` is a negative lookahead, which means that group is equivlaent to `.*` but in addition it fails if the four characters after that point are `test`. Basically this just makes `.*` only match the characters up until that happens, after which it backtracks and the following `(test)?` can match.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23403494/perl-matching-string-not-containing-pattern

Answer (score -1):

Since you're using Perl, this is a good way to do it.

Use this if you don't want to use any anchors.
Maybe you are not in a multi-line environment.
*Btw, anchors are a crutch avoid using them if possible,

it will expand your mind.*

`(this)(?|.*(test)|.*())`

https://regex101.com/r/1p4FVK/1

```
 ( this )                      # (1)
 (?|                           # Branch reset, reuse grp 2
      .* 
      ( test )                      # (2)
   |  
      .*  
      ( )                           # (2)
 )
```

Without the branch reset it's `(this)(?:.*(test)|.*())`
Replace with `$1 $2$3`

Comment: > anchors are a crutch ––– Please explain what you mean with that.